# Notification is Lost when when I minimized it

Tags: android, push-notification, minimize

I have an issue that when I get a notification in my device I open it and when I minimize the notification it is disappeared from the minimized app's list so i am no longer able to see my notification back.

Here is the code of messege handler Service

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    private void setNotification(String message,String bundledata)
    {
        NotificationManager  mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GcmNotificationRedirect.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("pushMessage", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("bundleData",bundledata);
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


       // NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(message))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setNumber(pushNumber);

            mBuilder.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.theme_color));
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);
            mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getNotificationIcon()));

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
```

This is the activity which will pass the data to appropriate activity..

```
//GcmNotificationRedirect
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pushRedirect();

    }

    private void pushRedirect()
    {
        pushMessage = getIntent().getStringExtra("pushMessage");
        bundleData = getIntent().getStringExtra("bundleData");
        parsePushNotifiactionJson(pushMessage,bundleData);
        finish();
    }

    private void parsePushNotifiactionJson(String pushMessage, String bundleJSONData){
        Intent pushNotiInetent = null;

        if(pushMessage!=null && bundleJSONData!=null) {
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(bundleJSONData);

                if (jsonObject.getString("type").equals(PRODUCT_PAGE)) {

                    pojo = new Push_Notification_Pojo(jsonObject.getString("productId"), jsonObject.getString("type"),pushMessage);
                    pushNotiInetent = new Intent(this, ProductDetail.class);
                    pushNotiInetent.putExtra("push_notification_pojo", pojo);
                    startActivity(pushNotiInetent);
                }

                else
                {
                    pojo = new Push_Notification_Pojo(jsonObject.getString("promotionId"), jsonObject.getString("type"), pushMessage, true);

                    if(pojo!=null)
                    {
                        pushNotiInetent = new Intent(this,PushNotificationPromotion.class);
                        pushNotiInetent.putExtra("pushMessage", pushMessage);
                        pushNotiInetent.putExtra("bundleData",bundleData);
                        startActivity(pushNotiInetent);
                    }
                }
                Log.d("Push",pojo.getType()+" "+pojo.getProductId()+" "+pojo.getPromotionId() );

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Everything is working fine but I am unable to get the notification back when I minimized it..

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean when you dismiss the notification. That's an expected behaviour. If you want to persist the notification, meaning to be always visible, you can use **setOngoing(true)**:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message))
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .setNumber(pushNumber);
```

To dismiss it, use

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

Regards,
Vladimir